# Scale all visible UIComponents, including navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit

I'm trying to emulate the "card view" that you get when you tap on a playing song in the music app in iOS 10. I've made a card that appears over the current view by attaching it to the application's key window, but now I need a way to scale down (or move backwards) the original view, including the navigation bar, while still having an image display behind it.

[image]

image view (full screen) 
view + navigation bar (scaled down, ~95%) 
tint view (full screen) 
card view

Is there a way to access the navigation bar + view to scale it down (or move backwards) and also apply the corner radius?